# What is the best color space for scene classification?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, classification

I have four classes city,roads,sea and forests and some train photos and test photos I would like to classify any coming test photo based on their color histograms so I was wondering which color space is the best for this application? also which histogram comparison method is the most accurate?

Comment: Too broad.  Colour is still something we don't completely understand.  There are so many colour spaces and each of them have their advantages and disadvantages that there wouldn't be one of them that would give you the best results.  Voting to close.

Comment: Well I meant for this particular problem not generally speaking

Comment: Until you've settled on a method of classification, it's hard to know whether a change of color space would help. Lots of people like LAB for its perceptual basis, but RGB isn't too bad in that regard. The spaces that separate out Hue are a little closer to the way people think of color so that helps if you're manually specifying a color region.

Comment: I am using nearest neighbor classifier